# The scalar convergence in $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is topologizable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, convexity, limits-and-convergence

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a separable Banach space and $\mathcal{C}(X)$ be the collection of all nonempty, closed and convex subsets of $X$. For any $C$ in  $\mathcal{C}(X)$ we set
$$
s(x^*, C) := \sup_{x\in C}{\langle  x^*, x \rangle}\qquad;\qquad \|C\| := \sup_{x\in C} \|x\|
$$
to define for the set $C$ respectively its support function $s(., C)$ and radius $\|C\|$.

On  $\mathcal{C}(X)$ we use the following convergence : a net  $\{C_\alpha\}$ convergent scalarly  to $C_\infty$ in  $\mathcal{C}(X)$ if
$$
\lim_\alpha s(x^*, C_\alpha)=s(x^*, C_\infty)\qquad \forall x^*\in X^*
$$

Can we say that the scalar convergence in  $\mathcal{C}(X)$ is topologizable ?

Comment: Isn't it just the initial topology with respect to the functions $s(x^*,-)$? So a prebase would be given by sets of the form $\{C\text{ such that }s(x^*,C)\in U\}$ for $x\in X^*$ and $U$ a open set of $\overline{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Do you know the Wijsman topology?

Comment: I just read the definition on Wikipedia. Is my comment not enough to answer your question?